# Proper way to write to C memory from go

Tags: c, go, pointers, garbage-collection, cgo

I would like to port a go program as a library by exporting some C APIs. In C it's common for a function to accept a buffer (pointer) as parameter (along with its size) and write the output to it.
For example (from C standard library)

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

This will write to the `*ptr` specified by the caller for at most `size*nmemb` bytes. The benefit of such design is that memory is managed by the caller, and thus the function does not need to deal with memory allocation. I want my API exported from go to be look like this as well.

However, I found there is no direct way to write to a pointer in go. So I created something like this (slight modification of case 6 of [this documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer)) that creates a `[]byte` object in go using the underlying memory of C.

```
// create a byte array using C memory for internal use
func createBuffer(buf unsafe.Pointer, size int) []byte {
    var res []byte
    hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&res))
    hdr.Data = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(buf))
    hdr.Len = size
    hdr.Cap = size
    return res
}
```

I then exported my function as the following (`readers` is a slice of `io.Reader`, `unsafe.Pointer` will have type `void*` after export) that will read some data to the C memory provided with at most `size` bytes.

```
//export read
func read(id int, buf unsafe.Pointer, size C.int) int {
    res, err := readers[id].Read(createBuffer(buf, int(size)))  // works
    //res, err := readers[id].Read(C.GoBytes(buf, size)) // does not work
    if err != nil {
        return -1
    }
    return res
}
```

This works as expected (i.e. in my C program, the buffer does contain the desired data after invoking `read`), but I am not sure whether this is the correct way to do so (i.e. whether there are memory issues especially related to garbage collection (GC)).

Suppose the resulted `[]byte` returned from `createBuffer` is not used anywhere else after `read` terminated, how will the memory get deallocated by GC? Will the GC also attempting to free `hdr.Data`, which is supposed to be a piece of memory managed by the C program? The [official documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader) provides quite a bit of warning about this. If this will cause GC problems, what is the correct way to do so? (I already tried `C.GoBytes(...)`, it seems to copy the underlying buffer and thus does not work)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do both memory safe and without creating intermediate buffers. You can have go slices that have a C "backing". See [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#turning-c-arrays-into-go-slices).

```
// export read function to C
func read(descriptorId int, buf *C.char, size C.size_t) C.int {
    stream := getCDescriptor(descriptorId)

    // pre-1.17:
    array := (*[1 << 28]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(buf))[:size:size]
    // as of 1.17:
    // array := unsafe.Slice(unsafe.Pointer(buf), size)

    n, err := stream.Read(array)
    if err != nil {
         // handle...
    }
    return C.int(n)
}
```